# How can I create a user option in Java

Tags: java, random, input, menu

**How can I complete this code for program of user option?**
Write and complete the following static methods in the program A1B1.java:

1. public static void showWelcome() :
   o display “Welcome!” on the console
2. public static int[] getRaNum() :
   o return 5 integers which are generated randomly from 21 to 98
3. public static void showMenu() :
   o display a menu which prompts user to select an option (Please refer to the Sample Program Output on the next page)
4. public static void main(String[] args) :
   o the program entry point

o The program runs continuously with loops, until exit by user. Each loop should:
o Display a menu (by calling the method showMenu())
o Ask user for an option (0, 1, 2, 3, or other integers)
o Based on the user input option, do the corresponding job, including properly calling the methods in the given class.
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class A1B1 { // declare a class, name A1B1

```
public static void showWelcome(){  // DO NOT MODIFY the method header
    // 1. METHOD BODY TO BE FINISHED BY STUDENT
}

public static String getCurTime(){ // GIVEN, DO NOT MODIFY
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); // current date & time as Calendar
    String curTimeStr = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":"
                    + c.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + ":"
                    + c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
    return curTimeStr;
}
public static int[] getRaNum(){  // DO NOT MODIFY the method header
    // 2. METHOD BODY TO BE FINISHED BY STUDENT
}

public static void showMenu(){  // DO NOT MODIFY the method header
    // 3. METHOD BODY TO BE FINISHED BY STUDENT
}

public static void main(String[] args){ // main() method, the entry point where the program starts
    
    
    System.out.println("\n>>> END of main(). Done by , x, x,x  <<<");
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample that reads UserInput. You can use Scanner class to do that if your input. You can use the same technique to complete your assignment :)
Do respond if you have questions.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {

  private InputReader inputReader;

  public Main() {

    inputReader = new InputReader(new Scanner(System.in));
  }

  class InputReader {
    private Scanner scanner;

    public InputReader(Scanner scanner) {
      this.scanner = scanner;
    }

    public String readName() {
      System.out.print("Enter your name:");
      return scanner.nextLine();
    }

    public int readAge() {
      System.out.print("Enter your age:");
      return Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
    }

  }

  class InputData {
    private String name;
    private int age;

    // Use Builder if the input data is large
    public InputData(String name, int age) {
      this.name = name;
      this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName() {
      return this.name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
      return this.age;
    }

    public String toString() {
      return "Name: " + name + "\t Age: " + age;
    }
  }

  public InputData getUserInput() {
    return new InputData(inputReader.readName(), 
                         inputReader.readAge());
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Main app = new Main();
    InputData data = app.getUserInput();
    System.out.println("Input is [" + data + "]");
    
  }
}
```